# Prove that if $G$ is an inﬁnite abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are ﬁnite then $G \cong C_{p^∞}$ for some prime $p.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove  that if $G$ is an inﬁnite abelian group all of whose proper subgroups are ﬁnite then $G \cong C_{p^∞}$ for some prime $p.$
>
> Is $C_{p^∞} \times C_{q^∞} \cong C_{p^∞}$ for $p \neq q$?

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can find a problem with the argument:

You've already deduced G is a torsion abelian group. And thus is a direct product of p-groups:

$$G\cong \text{Dr}_{p\in X} G_p $$

The set of primes over which the direct product is taken has to just consist of p. Otherwise G would have an infinite subgroup isomorphic to $C_{q^\infty}$.

The map $G\rightarrow pG$ is a homomorphism with kernel $G[p]$. Furthermore, both $pG$ and $G[p]$ are subgroups, and so one of them has to be finite. We can just look at $pG$. It has to either be $G$, or be a finite subgroup. $pG=\{pg|g\in G\}$ can't be finite because $G$ is infinite (and also that would mean $G[p]=\{x\in G|px=0\}$ is infinite, which can't happen).
Thus, $G=pG$, so $G$ is p-divisible.
Then the structure theorem for divisible groups says we can write $G$ as a product of $C_{p^\infty}$'s (there are no $\mathbb{Q}$'s here since we have a p-group). Again invoking the fact that we can't have an infinite subgroup isomorphic to $C_{q^\infty}$ for some $q\neq p$, we must have $G\cong C_{p^\infty}$ for a single $p$.

Comment: yo man!! Yeah, i figured this one out actually, well actually I got to the end where it says use the map $G \rightarrow pG$ but I haven't figured out how to use that clue. Other than that, i'm having trouble with certain parts of #5 >.<

Comment: The map is not a isomorphism because $G$ is gaurentee'd to have an element of order p by cauchy's theorem and so the kernel is non-empty. The quotient is isomorphic to the image because the map is onto. I think that the point is that the kernel is a proper subgroup by hypothesis and we are supposed to use that fact to find the isomorphism we are looking for but I still don't see it.

Comment: Yeah, I was wrong. It is not an isomorphism. But we can use that fact that $G/G[p]\cong pG$ to show that $G=pG$, so it's p-divisible for all primes p.

Comment: I think the argument that $G = pG$ needs a little more justification.

Comment: That is the trickiest part for me as well. Let's try this:

Case 1: G=pG. We hope this is the case because then G is divisible and we're done.
Case 2: pG<G. In this case $G[p]$ has to be infinite, so it has to be $G$. But $G[p]$ is just the p-primary component of $G$, whose torsion group will be isomorphic to a direct product of copies of $C_{p^\infty}$. Then we proceed as before, deducing that it has to be for a single prime p.